# How to sum up all records over one column in mysql?

Tags: mysql

is there a way to get sophistically the SUM(COUNTMINUS) and the SUM(COUNTPLUS) for each tradedate in mysql? Mayby by a UDF? Any advices are welcome! THANKS

I have following Table DATA: (Here I have limited to one TradeDate. But there are more TradeDates in it, one with the Countplus data and one with Countminus data.)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try [GROUP BY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) statement

```
SELECT TradeDate, SUM(market.Countminus) as Countminus, SUM(market.Countplus) as Countplus
FROM market
WHERE country = 'DE' and TradeDate = '2017-08-15'
GROUP BY TradeDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorryif I bother you, but there is a sum function:

```
     SELECT TradeDate,sum(market.Countminus),sum(market.Countplus) from market where country = 'DE' and TradeDate = '2017-08-15 00:00:00'  ;
```

Thanks,